# Habilitar botón Submit solo cuando el formulario este diligenciado MVC .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate

Tengo un formulario con validaciones en los DataAnnotations Required y con las librerías de jQuery Validation, todo esto funciona perfectamente, pero quisiera saber si de alguna manera puedo habilitar el botón Submit solo cuando el formulario sea valido, pues valide si podía acceder desde razor al ModelState y de esta manera controlarlo pero no fue posible. Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Hola Jager. *"Quisiera saber si de alguna manera puedo habilitar el botón Submit sólo cuando el formulario sea valido"*. Sí. Sí puedes. Cargas la vista con el botón deshabilitado y a través de javascript verificas que los campos sean válidos, y habilitas el botón en caso que lo sean. Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Si, comprendo que de esta manera podría solucionarlo, pero en el caso de MVC los DataAnnotations hacen esta funcionalidad directamente en la vista con jQuery Validation, pero la idea seria no crear una funcion de javascript para validar los campos, si no utilizar de alguna manera el jQuery Validation que renderiza MVC.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que, de **alguna manera** el `[DataAnnotation]` sepa que existe un botón de tipo `submit` que tenga que renderizar en la vista, que nunca ha sido declarado en la clase, y que cree el código javascript para habilitar el botón cuando le das click?  Ya leíste la [documentación de jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) para saber si lo que pides es posible?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre encontrar la siguiente solución.

Ya con las validaciones de los `[DataAnnotation]` y las librerías de jQuery Validation se puede acceder a la validación del formulario validando por eventos en los controles `input` o `select` de la siguiente manera:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('input').keyup(function() {
         var form = $( "#CreateForm" );
        if(form.valid()) {
           ValidateForm();
        }else{
            ValidateForm();
        }
     });
     $('select').change(function() {
         var form = $( "#CreateForm");
        if(form.valid()) {
           ValidateForm();
        }else{
            ValidateForm();
        }
     });
 });

});
```

Se podría ajustar el evento al que se desee.

```
function ValidateForm(){
   var form = $( "#CreateForm" );
   if(form.valid()) {
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
   }else{
      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
   }
}
```

El `form.valid()` devuelve el valor `booleano`dependiendo de los `[DataAnnotation]`, ya las líneas  `$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);` cambian el input `submit` de `disabled` a `enableb` respectivamente.

Tambien se puede validar en la [documentación de jQuery](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) como lo menciono @ariel

Comment: Excelente! Gracias por la explicación!